# How to deal with invalid Paypal order email adresses?

Tags: email, paypal, gmail

I use paypal checkout buttons and IPN protocol. Our buttons and IPN have been OK for years ... 99.5% of the time.

After each command, we ask the client to check his order and address. 
It happens that some of the email addresses we receive from paypal are invalid and we receive an error mail.

Example error message :

```
The mail system dl*n**l@gmail.com : host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:400c:c02::1b]
    said: 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist.
    Please try 550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for
    typos or 550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at 550 5.1.1
    https://support.google.com/mail/?p=NoSuchUser i14si15070073wrm.207 - gsmtp
    (in reply to RCPT TO command)
```

How is that possible that paypal didnt check these email adresses ?
And more important : how can i best deal with these situations ?

I tried to send mails to these adresses using other mail providers for the from: and other smtp servers, but these client's email adresses are really wrong (as says the error message).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PayPal does not know the current (nor necessarily the former) validity of payer email addresses, since it is entirely possible to use an unconfirmed email address on a PayPal account. If you need to confirm a customer’s email address, email them a link/code for validation.